# Achieve concurrency in Kafka consumers

Tags: parallel-processing, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, consumer

We are working on parallelising our Kafka consumer to process more number of records to handle the Peak load. One way, we are already doing is through spinning up as many consumers as many partitions within the same consumer group.

Our Consumer deals with making an API call which is synchronous as of now. We felt making this API call asynchronous will make our consumer handle more load. Hence, we are trying to making the API call Asynchronous and in its response we are increasing the offset. However we are seeing an issue with this:

By making the API call Asynchronous, we may get the response for the last record first and none of the previous record's API calls haven't initiated or done by then. If we commit the offset as soon as we receive the response of the last record, the offset would get changed to the last record. In the meantime if the consumer restarts or partition rebalances, we will not receive any record before the last record we committed the offset as. With this, we will miss out the unprocessed records.

As of now we already have 25 partitions. We are looking forward to understand if someone have achieved parallelism without increasing the partitions or increasing the partitions is the only way to achieve parallelism (to avoid offset issues).

Comment: You are not providing enough information,  You've provided the fact that the Records appear to be reliant on the previous record being processed first, you need to explain the data structure and Why it is reliant on previous records, from the loose sound of it you need to either process those records together, or make a mechanism for synchronizing that proccess.  currently as is the question is Too Broad

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to decouple (if only at first) the reading of the messages from the processing of these messages. Next look at how many concurrent calls you can make to your API as it doesn't make any sense to call it more frequently than the server can handle, asynchronously or not. If the number of concurrent API calls is roughly equal to the number of partitions you have in your topic, then it doesn't make sense to call the API asynchronously.

If the number of partitions is significantly less than the max number of possible concurrent API calls then you have a few choices.  You could try to make the max number of concurrent API calls with fewer threads (one per consumer) by calling the API's asynchronously as you suggest, or you can create more threads and make your calls synchronously.  Of course, then you get into the problem of how can your consumers hand their work off to a greater number of shared threads, but that's exactly what streaming execution platforms like Flink or Storm do for you.  Streaming platforms (like Flink) that offer checkpoint processing can also handle your problem of how to handle offset commits when messages are processed out of order. You could roll your own checkpoint processing and roll your own shared thread management, but you'd have to really want to avoid using a streaming execution platform.

Finally, you might have more consumers than max possible concurrent API calls, but then I'd suggest that you just have fewer consumers and share partitions, not API calling threads.

And, of course, you can always change the number of your topic partitions to make your preferred option above more feasible.

Either way, to answer your specific question you want to look at how Flink does checkpoint processing with Kafka offset commits.  To oversimplify (because I don't think you want to roll your own), the kafka consumers have to remember not only the offsets they just committed, but they have to hold on to the previous committed offsets, and that defines a block of messages flowing though your application. Either that block of messages in its entirety is processed all the way through or you need to rollback the processing state of each thread to the point where the last message in the previous block was processed.  Again, that's a major oversimplification, but that's kinda how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at kafka `batch` processing. In a nutshell: you can setup huge `batch.size` with a little number (or even single) of `partitions`. As far, as whole `batch` of `messages` consumed at `consumer` side (i.e. in ram memory) - you can parallelize this messages in any way you want.

I would really like to share links, but their number rolls over the web hole.

***UPDATE***

In terms of committing offsets - you can do this for whole `batch`.
In general, kafka doesn't achieve target performance requirements by abusing partitions number, but rather relying on `batch` processing.

I already saw a lot of projects, suffering from partitions scaling (you may see issues later, during rebalancing for example). The rule of thumb - look at every available `batch` setting first.